# Can Doxygen output members purely in order of declaration?

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation, doxywizard

Which Doxygen option can completely disable sorting members by type (Private / Public / Method / Variable), and output members purely based on the order in which they were declared?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is impossible via the config options. The best you can do is:

```
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS = NO
```

which disables alphabetical sorting of members.

Comment: At least in Version 1.8, setting `SORT_MEMBER_DOCS = NO` will document the functions in declaration order.